# write lines to file and when there 5 lines in needs to execute a statement vbscript

Tags: function, vbscript, count, line, text-files

here is a code which i wanne run on background so no windowmessages. The meaning of it is that it checks a connection. If there isn't a connection it writes a error to a file. a function reads that file if there are 5 lines it should create a event-error. The problem is that the last part doesn't work correctly.

my qeustion is can somebody fix it or help me fixing it. Here is the code:

```
strDirectory = "Z:\text2"
strFile = "\foutmelding.txt"
strText = "De connectie is verbroken" 
strWebsite = "www.helmichbeens.com"


If PingSite(strWebsite) Then WScript.Quit    'Website is pingable - no further action required
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

RecordSingleEvent
If EventCount >= 5 Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile strDirectory & strFile
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strCommand = "eventcreate /T Error /ID 100 /L Scripts /D " & _
    Chr(34) & "Test event." & Chr(34)
    WshShell.Run strcommand
End if
'------------------------------------
'Record a single event in a text file
'------------------------------------
Sub RecordSingleEvent
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & strFile, 8, True)
    objTextFile.WriteLine(Now & strText)
    objTextFile.Close
End sub
'----------------
'Ping my web site
'----------------
Function PingSite( myWebsite )
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )
    objHTTP.Open "GET", "http://" & myWebsite & "/", False
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MyApp 1.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
    On Error Resume Next
    objHTTP.Send
    PingSite = (objHTTP.Status = 200)
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------
'Counts the number of lines inside the text file
'-----------------------------------------------
Function EventCount()
    strData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & strFile,ForReading).ReadAll
    arrLines = Split(strData,vbCrLf)
    EventCount = UBound(arrLines)
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

thats the code you can copy it to see it your self. i thank you for your time and intrest

Greets helmich

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because function EventCount sets `objFSO=nothing`, so,

```
If EventCount >= 5 Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile strDirectory & strFile
```

fails

Answer (score 0):

Use the logevent method of the Shell object

```
If EventCount >= 5 Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile strDirectory & strFile
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Call WshShell.LogEvent(1, "Test Event")
End if
```

You don't need to run a separate command

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the problem is this

Windows host script gives a error

Line:41
Char:2
Translation of error: the data required for this operation are not yet available
code: 80070057
source: WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
thats the problem and i do not know how to fix it

it has something to do that he can't read the lines in the txtfile and then not execute the create event command